# Magento SQL query hogs all resources

Tags: php, mysql, magento

In Magento backend when I click on Manage Customers it hogs all MySQL resources, runs for hours until I manually kill it.

Here's the query: http://codepad.org/WfXS7723

I ran "explain" on it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kq6Gq.png

Answer (score 2):

this query will kill every mysql server unless you make some indices. Start with indexing columns that are referred in join's ON clause.

-- edit: 
Especially ones that are referred by const value, like `` at_prefix`.`attribute_id `` from first join.

Comment: I'm new to Magento and am scared if I just run out there and start adding indexes I'm gonna mess something up badly.